# pita bread crust too hard

Tags: baking, bread, dough, pita

I've baked my first pita bread in home, the pockets was almost well formed but the crust is hard, crunchy.

I've applied some variations because of time/number/ingredients restrictions, in particular:

- I've used two part of white flour (farina 00) and one part of whole-wheat flour
- I've made the pitas a bit thin, say 1/7-1/8 inch.
- I've raised the dough for about 1 hour and 45 minutes.

Which are the factors that make the crust so crispy?

EDIT:

About the cooking method I cooked at about 500 F for 4 minutes, turn 2 minutes, the dough was puffed after about 2-3 minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cook only until it is fully puffed.  If that isn't enough, try folding them right after taking them out, and put them in a paper bag.  They'll steam themselves briefly and keep the crust soft.

Answer (score 4):

We cook our pitas on the stovetop on a very hot cast iron skillet. You can monitor each pita carefully that way. Put the pita in the pan and flip it when it puffs. You can encourage the small puff bubbles to join by gently pushing down on them with a spatula. Once the pan is hot, each pita only takes about 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Try lowering your oven temperature by 25 degrees at a time, and/or shortening how long you cook it until just lightly browned.

Comment: I have found that cooking them extremely hot is best to get them to puff properly, even if they only take two minutes to cook.

Comment: I get a successful puff at 450 degrees F.  They burn at 500.